# Появление данных

Tags: html, javascript, css

У меня такая проблема: не получается, чтобы при вставке в php страницу, в этом коде данные (содержимое информера) были завёрнуты

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function toggleInformer() {
        // ищем нужный нам тег информера
        var elm = document.getElementById("informer");

        // если тег найден, обрабатываем его
        if (elm) {
            // меняем видимость элемента на противоположную
            if (elm.style.visibility == "visible") {
                elm.style.visibility = "hidden";
            } else {
                elm.style.visibility = "visible";
            }

        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggleInformer(); return false;">Информер</a>
<div id="informer" style="border:1px solid red; color: green; visibility: visible;">
    Содержимое информера
</div>
```

Comment: То ли я пьян, то чего-то не хвата. А где php-код?

Comment: То ли метки не те:)

Comment: Ссылка на статью  http://on-line-teaching.com/js/js.layers.htm

Comment: к php вопрос не относится, это html + javascript

Comment: Чета рассмешил ты меня,брат-программист! Вахаху!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня "Информер" исчезает по клику, но место за ним остаётся зарезервированным.
Чтобы он сворачивался, надо ещё один параметр стиля менять.

Добавьте в скрипт после elm.style.visibility = "hidden";

```
elm.style.display = "none";
```

и в ветку else соответственно

```
elm.style.display = "block";
```

(visibility можно оставить для совместимости со старыми браузерами)

Comment: Всё равно при открытии страницы сразу появляеться Содержимое информера

Comment: ну так начальное состояние вы видите в html в строке

    style="border:1px solid red; color: green;visibility:visible;" 

напишите там вместо visibility:visible;

    visibility:hidden;display:none;